# Timeout and Retry Logic in Circuit Breaker pattern using Polly

Tags: c#, timeout, httpclient, circuit-breaker, polly

I am implementing Circuit Breaker pattern with HttpClientFactory and Polly using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/implement-circuit-breaker-pattern#implement-circuit-breaker-pattern-with-httpclientfactory-and-polly) tutorial and here's the code below that i wrote based on my understanding of the tutorial. `RetryHttpRequest` class is the class where HttpClient is used.

```
  services.AddHttpClient<IRetryHttpRequest, RetryHttpRequest>()
                    .SetHandlerLifetime(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))
                    .AddPolicyHandler(GetCircuitBreakerPolicy());

  static IAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage> GetCircuitBreakerPolicy()
        {
            return HttpPolicyExtensions
                .HandleTransientHttpError()
                .CircuitBreakerAsync(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        }
```

1. For `SetHandlerLifetime`, does the lifetime here mean per API request? So if I do retry for 3 times, each retry should take no more than 3 seconds. It is interesting that the default lifetime is 2 minutes which I think is too long.
2. How does `SetHandlerLifetime(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3))` and `CircuitBreakerAsync(5, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30))` related to each other and work with each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SetHandlerLifetime(...)` is not to do with the timeout of individual calls. It is about [how long `HttpClient`s provided by HttpClientFactory reuse the same `HttpClientHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.httpclientbuilderextensions.sethandlerlifetime?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.0), which provides a [trade-off between optimising resources and reacting to external DNS changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-3.0#httpclient-and-lifetime-management).

For applying timeouts via HttpClientFactory, and combining that with retry policies, see [Polly's documentation on applying timeout via HttpClientFactory](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory#use-case-applying-timeouts).